# GeoServer CoverageView provides the same value for u and v components

Tags: geoserver, sld

Following these two tutorials I'm trying to create a currents layer:

[https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/accessing_multidim/coverageview.html]

[https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/accessing_multidim/rtx/currents.html]

The GeoServer (2.16) recognized the two component (u,v) during the coverageview creation step (we used imagemosaic with netcdf), however on the layer preview on every point the output value has an equal value for both components and the arrows have just two directions (45° and 135°). Only a few vertical arrows but the values there are Null.

[image]
I report the coverage.xml:

```
   <coverage>
       <id>CoverageInfoImpl--6d8ff4db:17998f83044:-727a</id>
       <name>currentView</name>
       <nativeName>currentView</nativeName>
       <namespace>
         <id>NamespaceInfoImpl--76dd0006:1732e4f1b7d:7978</id>
       </namespace>
    <title>currentView</title>
    <description>Generated from ImageMosaic</description>
    <keywords>
       <string>currentView</string>
       <string>WCS</string>
       <string>ImageMosaic</string>
    </keywords>
    <nativeCRS>GEOGCS["WGS 84", DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]</nativeCRS>
    <srs>EPSG:4326</srs>
    <nativeBoundingBox>
       <minx>12.1974998095456</minx>
       <maxx>13.9024996182498</maxx>
       <miny>44.0982555092358</miny>
       <maxy>45.8028751670337</maxy>
       <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
    </nativeBoundingBox>
    <latLonBoundingBox>
       <minx>12.1974998095456</minx>
       <maxx>13.9024996182498</maxx>
       <miny>44.0982555092358</miny>
       <maxy>45.8028751670337</maxy>
       <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
    </latLonBoundingBox>
    <projectionPolicy>REPROJECT_TO_DECLARED</projectionPolicy>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <metadata>
       <entry key="elevation">
          <dimensionInfo>
             <enabled>true</enabled>
             <presentation>LIST</presentation>
             <units>EPSG:5030</units>
             <unitSymbol>m</unitSymbol>
             <defaultValue>
                <strategy>MAXIMUM</strategy>
             </defaultValue>
             <nearestMatchEnabled>false</nearestMatchEnabled>
          </dimensionInfo>
       </entry>
       <entry key="COVERAGE_VIEW">
          <coverageView>
             <coverageBands>
                <coverageBand>
                   <inputCoverageBands class="singleton-list">
                       <inputCoverageBand>
                          <coverageName>u</coverageName>
                       </inputCoverageBand>
                  </inputCoverageBands>
                  <definition>u</definition>
                  <index>0</index>
                  <compositionType>BAND_SELECT</compositionType>
              </coverageBand>
              <coverageBand>
                 <inputCoverageBands class="singleton-list">
                    <inputCoverageBand>
                       <coverageName>v</coverageName>
                    </inputCoverageBand>
                </inputCoverageBands>
                <definition>v</definition>
                <index>1</index>
                <compositionType>BAND_SELECT</compositionType>
             </coverageBand>
         </coverageBands>
         <name>currentView</name>
         <envelopeCompositionType>INTERSECTION</envelopeCompositionType>
         <selectedResolution>BEST</selectedResolution>
         <selectedResolutionIndex>-1</selectedResolutionIndex>
      </coverageView>
    </entry>
    <entry key="DirectDownload.Key">
       <directDownloadSettings>
         <directDownloadEnabled>false</directDownloadEnabled>
         <maxDownloadSize>0</maxDownloadSize>
      </directDownloadSettings>
    </entry>
    <entry key="time">
       <dimensionInfo>
         <enabled>true</enabled>
         <presentation>LIST</presentation>
         <units>ISO8601</units>
         <defaultValue>
            <strategy>MAXIMUM</strategy>
         </defaultValue>
         <nearestMatchEnabled>true</nearestMatchEnabled>
         <acceptableInterval>PT12H/PT12H</acceptableInterval>
       </dimensionInfo>
    </entry>
    <entry key="cachingEnabled">false</entry>
    <entry key="dirName">Crea_PHY_UV_currentView</entry>
    </metadata>
    <store class="coverageStore">
       <id>CoverageStoreInfoImpl--6d8ff4db:17998f83044:-7839</id>
    </store>
    <serviceConfiguration>false</serviceConfiguration>
    <nativeFormat>ImageMosaic</nativeFormat>
    <grid dimension="2">
    <range>
        <low>0 0</low>
        <high>341 489</high>
    </range>
    <transform>
        <scaleX>0.004999999439015108</scaleX>
        <scaleY>-0.0034859297705478356</scaleY>
        <shearX>0.0</shearX>
        <shearY>0.0</shearY>
        <translateX>12.199999809265108</translateX>
        <translateY>45.80113220214842</translateY>
    </transform>
    <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
</grid>
     <supportedFormats>
        <string>GEOTIFF</string>
        <string>GIF</string>
        <string>PNG</string>
        <string>JPEG</string>
        <string>TIFF</string>
    </supportedFormats>
    <interpolationMethods>
        <string>nearest neighbor</string>
        <string>bilinear</string>
        <string>bicubic</string>
    </interpolationMethods>
    <defaultInterpolationMethod>bicubic</defaultInterpolationMethod>
    <dimensions>
        <coverageDimension>
            <name>u</name>
            <description>GridSampleDimension[-Infinity,Infinity]</description>
            <range>
                <min>-inf</min>
                <max>inf</max>
            </range>
            <dimensionType>
                <name>REAL_32BITS</name>
            </dimensionType>
        </coverageDimension>
        <coverageDimension>
            <name>v</name>
            <description>GridSampleDimension[-Infinity,Infinity]</description>
            <range>
                <min>-inf</min>
                <max>inf</max>
            </range>
            <dimensionType>
            <name>REAL_32BITS</name>
            </dimensionType>
        </coverageDimension>
    </dimensions>
    <requestSRS>
        <string>EPSG:4326</string>
    </requestSRS>
    <responseSRS>
        <string>EPSG:4326</string>
    </responseSRS>
        <parameters>
            <entry>
                <string>BackgroundValues</string>
                <null/>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>OVERVIEW_POLICY</string>
                <string>QUALITY</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>MergeBehavior</string>
                <string>FLAT</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>AllowMultithreading</string>
                <boolean>false</boolean>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>MaxAllowedTiles</string>
                <int>-1</int>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>ExcessGranuleRemoval</string>
                <string>NONE</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>OutputTransparentColor</string>
                <null/>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>USE_JAI_IMAGEREAD</string>
                <boolean>true</boolean>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>Bands</string>
                <null/>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>RescalePixels</string>
                <boolean>true</boolean>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>Filter</string>
                <null/>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>InputTransparentColor</string>
                <null/>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>SUGGESTED_TILE_SIZE</string>
                <string>512,512</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>Accurate resolution computation</string>
                <boolean>false</boolean>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>SORTING</string>
                <null/>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>FootprintBehavior</string>
                <string>None</string>
            </entry>
        </parameters>
    <nativeCoverageName>currentView</nativeCoverageName>
    </coverage>
```

In the image below the coverageview configuration:
[image]

Is there is something I should check to let the GeoServer discriminate between the two components?

Comment: Can you share the coverage view configuration too?

Comment: Question is changed with the integration of the coverage view configuration image

Comment: That looks ok, what about the style?

Comment: the style is basically a cut and paste of [link]https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/accessing_multidim/rtx/currents.html with a change for the name of variables. instead of u-component_of_current_surface I used u.